# ERLANG function which is like a while loop while(true)

Tags: erlang

I am very new to ERLANG. So, what I want to do is writing a while loop which works until true. Just like `while(true){x=x+1}` in java. I want to write that kind of a function. As well as I want to run bellow command in that while loop. So what is the format to enter this command.

```
curl -v -k -X POST "https://localhost:8243/raspberrypi/1.0.0/device/vf98e6a7atyp/bulb?state=on" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 38180797-3181-3839-900d-bdaf259f056a"
```

Can anyone help me please???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that you would do with loops in other languages are done with recursive function calls in Erlang.  So try something like this:

```
run_forever() ->
    Output = os:cmd("curl -v -k -X POST 'https://localhost:8243/raspberrypi/1.0.0/device/vf98e6a7atyp/bulb?state=on' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 38180797-3181-3839-900d-bdaf259f056a'"),
    io:format("Output from command:~n~s~n", [Output]),
    %% Don't want to repeat too quickly!  Sleep for five seconds
    timer:sleep(5000),
    run_forever().
```

So this function does something and then calls itself at the end.  In some other languages, you would worry about the call stack growing infinitely, but in Erlang we have something called "tail call optimisation", which means that if the last thing a function does is calling another function (possibly itself), then the stack frame of the current function is simply replaced with the one of the called function, and the stack size stays the same.

Comment: I want to sub string a string from tail... I want to get last 5 characters.. Is it possible in erlang??

Comment: Please create a new question for that.